# Laravel api passport not expire

Tags: php, laravel

Using `passport` for api authentication, everything working fine, I can create token, revoke and etc but problem is it won't expire.

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            Passport::routes();
            Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinute(1));
            Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
            Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinute(1));
        }
    }
```

**auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'sellers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

**api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
... routes...
```

It should expire `token` after `1 minute!` but nothing happen, still can access to those protected routes, I'm not laravel expert, should I do something more? or I missed something to do?

Comment: Refresh token and access token should not expire at the same time.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I changed it, but still same